# @android:drawable resources in manifest file?

Tags: android-manifest, google-play, android-resources

I would like to use the stock android icon for settings as the icon in my settings activity. The problem is when use the following line in the manifest I get an error when I upload to the google play store.

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
```

Error is something like "Server can not process apk file. Try again." Google suggested running the aapt tool on an unsigned apk and check for errors. That returns the error android:icon doesn't point to a valid resource.

I don't know exactly what the error codes are because the problem is fixed if I delete the line and that's what I did and uploaded the code already. What I'm really after is how would I put the stock android settings icon in my app. I'm also supporting lower than API8 so I'm using a PreferencesActivity for my settings page.

here is the full settings activity in the manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".ShowSettingsActivity"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
    android:label="@string/menu_settings" >
</activity>
```